# Textbox PreviewTextInput - accept only numbers and ':'

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have this code:

```
foreach (char ch in e.Text)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(ch))
                e.Handled = true;
            else
            {
                if(!(ch.Equals(':')))
                    e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

when there is only

```
if (!Char.IsDigit(ch))
                e.Handled = true;
```

I can write numbers and when I use only the second if(), I can write only ' : '.
But when I use both of them I can't write anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use boolean logic:

```
foreach (var ch in e.Text)
{
    if (!(Char.IsDigit(ch) || ch.Equals(':')))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be using a linq statement.  It comes down to personal preference but many find linq to be more readable.

```
e.Handled = !e.Text.Any(x => Char.IsDigit(x) || ':'.Equals(x));
```

It's a fairly easy one liner and with the coming of c# 6 the entire method could be written as a lambda function like so:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) =>
    e.Handled = !e.Text.Any(x => Char.IsDigit(x) || ':'.Equals(x));
```

Keep in mind that PreviewTextInput does not handle space characters and these methods will not filter them out. An explanation is provided on the [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/446ec083-04c8-43f2-89dc-1e2521a31f6b/textboxs-previewtextinput-event-does-not-trigger-on-spaces-input?forum=wpf)

> Because some IMEs will treat whitespace keystroke as part of the text composition process, that's why it eats up by Avalon to report correct composited text through TextInput event.